# Using AWS rekognition for recognizing people in an image

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

According to AWS documentation, SearchFacesByImage is used to search for faces in a collection that match the largest face in a supplied image.

Is there a way to search for a face matching ANY face in the supplied image?

Answer (score 1):

The docs for [`SearchFacesByImage`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_SearchFacesByImage.html) provide the solution to your problem:

> Note:
>
> To search for all faces in an input image, you might first call the **IndexFaces** operation, and then **use the face IDs returned** in subsequent calls to the **SearchFaces** operation.
>
> You can also call the **DetectFaces** operation and use the bounding boxes in the response to make face crops, which then you can pass in to the **SearchFacesByImage** operation.

I would recommend going ahead with the first recommendation ([`IndexFaces`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_IndexFaces.html), [`SearchFaces`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_SearchFaces.html)) but you are free to go with either.